# Used Fish Grease

Tags: storage-method

I fried fish in my indoor turkey deep fryer last week. It's been outside on my back porch since that day. The temperature outside has been up and down. Although the top has been closed since then. Is it still ok to use it again?

Comment: *The temperature outside has been up and down* From what to what? How old is the grease (how often has it been used). Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Even when it's safe to reuse oil, remember that if someone has a fish/seafood allergy, they can be harmed by eating something cooked in oil previously used for fish or seafood. We always keep oil used for fish or seafood separate from oil used for other foods. And, it's actually a regulation here in foodservice that a separate fryer must be used for fish or seafood.

Comment: Also the oil left from the frying the fish smells of...well, fish. So if you fry something in that oil it will definitely have an aftertaste and smell of fish. If that's your intention - by all means, go for it. Personally I always dispose of the oil if fish has been fried in it. In order to not waste the oil I generally fry other things in it multiple times (potatoes for example) and at the end of its "life" I do the fish. I do prefer to bake or boil the fish. It's healthier and not that heavy on the stomach.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, it's fine to reuse deep-fry oil. In a lot of restaurants, fryer oil only gets changed when it starts to smoke or make food taste "off". It is not necessary to refrigerate used oil. Assuming it's only used for safe food, oil will taste bad long before it will become unsafe (if it ever really does).

Kenji Lopez-Alt of Serious Eats wrote a [great article](http://www.seriouseats.com/2013/09/ask-the-food-lab-how-many-times-can-i-reuse-fry-oil.html) about reusing fryer oil. In it, he explains how the hydrophobic nature of oil drives moisture out of the food. Assuming the oil reached actual frying temperature (I've never seen a recipe that called for less than 325F/165C), there is no moisture left in those food bits that get left in the oil. Pathogens need moisture to survive and multiply.

For quality sake, ideally, fryer oil should be filtered daily. Leaving bits for days at varied temperatures could negatively affect the flavor, especially since you were frying fish. In the article linked above, Kenji speaks of a technique for cleaning fryer oil using gelatin in much the same way you can use gelatin to clarify stock. I have been meaning to experiment with that, but Kenji is a solidly reliable source so I'll take his word for it. If your fryer oil tastes less than clean, it's worth trying. Fryer oil is expensive!

Relatively harmless oxidation and degradation will eventually cause your oil to not taste good, but it's a common thing to actually add some of the old dirty oil to the new clean oil when cleaning a fryer. Super fresh oil doesn't taste as good as gently used :)

Extremely dirty, stinky oil does produce low levels of certain toxins and possible carcinogens, but not before many uses. As the oil degrades, its smoke point will drop. Smoking oil is not good eats.

Comment: I agree with this, but I would specify that the oil should be filtered before storage.  I wouldn't consider oil that has had bits and pieces from the last fry session sitting around in it for days to be "safe", necessarily.

Comment: @senschen I agree that oil should be filtered for quality, but it's not necessary for safety. I've worked in and run more than my fair share of greasy spoons and have endured more than a few safety inspections. In no jurisdiction I have ever worked was filtering the oil required by regulations. Deep frying forces the moisture out of those 'bits' that stay in the oil (although I am making the assumption that the oil is hot enough that it's actually frying). Without water, pathogens can't survive or multiply. I'll add a bit more to the answer to address that. Thanks for pointing out the issue.

Comment: Ah, I always assumed filtering was a safety thing.  Makes sense its just a quality issue though, they *did* use oil as a preservative back in the old days...  Excellent update, though.  +1!

Answer (score 0):

Fist strain the oil. In Asia I use a oil can with strainer.  In America I find a screen coffee filter will work with warm oil. Frying potatoes in the oil will remove taste in oil.  Once oil is strained put in sealed jug, bottle for reuse. Or oil can. Oil last a long time if not burnt. Or left with to much other matter in it to burn in the oil.